# Looking for a sequence with $4$ limit points

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Based on the definition, $x$   is a limit point of  $S$  if for all $\epsilon>0$  , there is a point $y \in S \backslash \{ x \}$  with $d(x,y)<\epsilon$.

I'm looking for a sequence of real numbers that has $4$ distinct limit points in the extended real line such that its superior limit is equal to $0$ and its inferior limit is equal to $-\infty$.

Can someone give me an example with an explanation please.

Comment: Like $0,-1-\frac1n,-1+\frac1n,-n$

Comment: You can divide the natural numbers in four infinite subsets and have the sequence behave accordingly on each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$
a_n = 
\begin{cases}
-n & n \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \\
-2 & n \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
-1 & n \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \\
0 &  n \equiv 3 \pmod 4
\end{cases}
$$

Sequence begins like 
$$
-2,-1,0,-4,-2,-1,0,-8,-2,-1,0,-12,-2,-1,0,-16,\ldots
$$
Since $-2,-1,$ and $0$ appear infinitely often, they are limit points.  Obviously, $0$ is the superior limit, since it's a limit and every element is $\leq 0$, and the inferior limit is $-\infty$ since it is unbounded below.